# MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit ElementHost DatePicker Selected/Current Date not displayed properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

For a production application we want to display a DatePicker inside an ElementHost in a Windows Forms application, but we get the issue that the SelectedDate and CurrentDate are not readable, because the numbers won't be shown.

We can't find the issue inside the xaml style of MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit, because we aren't experienced enough.

[image]

It got already an issue on the [github project page](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/987) but nobody seems to answer or have a look at it.
There is also a [github repo](https://github.com/uPloraX/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit_DatePicker_WinForms_Issue) with the reproduced bug.

Comment: What is your Windows 10 version?

Comment: My Windows 10 Version is 10.0.17134 Build 17134. But the bug also appeared in Windows 7 SP1

Comment: It should be supported on your version - seems bug...

Comment: First, this happens for a WPF app as well, so the fact that you're hosting it in Winforms has nothing to do with it. This is not really a bug, but a matter of customizing what you want. The effect you mentioned is due to a `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` for the `Selected` and `Today` visual states. Just comment it out and [the "problem" goes away](https://imgur.com/OyjPLAD). As a suggestion, take advantage of `BasedOn`, changing only the `ControlTemplate` in order to make it less verbose.

Comment: We published full source code solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/jsanalytics/MaterialDesignDatePicker), [YouTube](https://youtu.be/dS2n1LdVB8E) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TradePattern).

Comment: **Note**: sometimes VS XAML editor gets a little "whiny & glitchy" and starts throwing  _**The resource "abc" could not be resolved**_, where _"abc"_ is one of the `MateriaDesign` styles. The way we deal with it is to do some "fake" editing on the file, save it, recompile and it all works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you post this as an answer I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're looking for can be achieved by proper Style/Template customization. The crux of the case is to simply eliminate an `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` present in the `ControlTemplate` of `CalendarDayButton`. Also, in order to apply such customization, one needs to consider the *HAS A* relationship between `CalendarDayButton`, `Calendar` and `DatePicker`. This is a textbook case where `BasedOn` comes-in very handy.

Here's the XAML that does the trick:

```
<Style x:Key="MyCalendarDayButton"
       TargetType="CalendarDayButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignCalendarDayButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="{x:Null}" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" Storyboard="{x:Null}" To="{x:Null}"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightBackground"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="{x:Null}" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" Storyboard="{x:Null}" To="{x:Null}"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBackground"/>
                                    <!--
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    -->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CalendarButtonFocusStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="{x:Null}" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" Storyboard="{x:Null}" To="{x:Null}"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CalendarButtonUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="DayButtonFocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ActiveStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="{x:Null}" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" Storyboard="{x:Null}" To="{x:Null}"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Active"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Inactive"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="{x:Null}" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" Storyboard="{x:Null}" To="{x:Null}"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RegularDay"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Today">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="TodayBackground"/>
                                    <!--
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextElement.Foreground)" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    -->
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BlackoutDayStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="{x:Null}" GeneratedDuration="0" GeneratedEasingFunction="{x:Null}" Storyboard="{x:Null}" To="{x:Null}"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalDay"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BlackoutDay">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HighlightingBorder"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.38" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalText"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="TodayBackground" Fill="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueLightBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="SelectedBackground" Fill="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="HighlightingBorder" Opacity="1">
                        <Ellipse x:Name="HighlightBackground" Fill="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="NormalText" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" TextElement.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="5,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="DayButtonFocusVisual" Opacity="0" Stroke="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyCalendarStyle" 
       TargetType="Calendar"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDatePickerCalendarPortrait}">
    <Setter Property="CalendarDayButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyCalendarDayButton}"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MyDatePickerStyle" 
       TargetType="DatePicker" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDatePicker}">
    <Setter Property="CalendarStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyCalendarStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

And here's a side-by-side comparison between the resulting custom style as shown above and the original, standard `MaterialDesign` style:

[image]

Full source code solution for this sample project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/jsanalytics/MaterialDesignDatePicker).